# The searchview in recyclerview doesn't select the correct position after searching

Tags: android-studio, android-recyclerview, searchview

I've found many people answering this question, and many worked for them, such as holder.setIsRecyclable(true); .however none of them worked for me. I can't seem to find the reason why... I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me.  I think it has something to do with my filter, or my adapter.. I'm not too sure..

This is my Activity

```
public class GenreActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private AdapterRecyclerView mAdapter;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ArrayList<DifferentGenres> differentGenres;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceStat) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceStat);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_genre)

    //toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Genre");


     differentGenreList();

     RecyclerLayoutAdapter();

     onClickGenre();

}


//methhod for clicking genre
public void onClickGenre(){

    mAdapter.setmOnItemClickListener(new 
AdapterRecyclerView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            GenreActivity.this.mAdapter.updateList(differentGenres);

            switch (position) {
                case 0:

            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+ 
differentGenres.get(position).getmGenre(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(GenreActivity.this, 
SelectedGenre.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

//building recycler view
public void RecyclerLayoutAdapter(){
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mAdapter = new AdapterRecyclerView(differentGenres);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}

//arraylist for genres
public void differentGenreList(){
    differentGenres = new ArrayList<>();
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Action"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Adventure"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Animation"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Biography"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Comedy"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Crime"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Drama"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Family"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Fantasy"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("History"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Horror"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Music"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Musical"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Mystery"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Romance"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Sport"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Superhero"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("Thriller"));
    differentGenres.add(new DifferentGenres("War"));




}

//search icon
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.searchGenre);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return true;
}

//search filter
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

    String input = newText.toLowerCase();
    ArrayList<DifferentGenres> filtered = new ArrayList<>();

    for(DifferentGenres differentGenres : differentGenres){

if(differentGenres.getmGenre().toLowerCase().contains(
input.toLowerCase())){

            filtered.add(differentGenres);

        }


    }
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    mAdapter.updateList(filtered);
    return true;
  }

}
```

This is my Adapter

```
    public class AdapterRecyclerView extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterRecyclerView.GenreViewHolder> {

        private ArrayList<DifferentGenres> mGenreItems;


        private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

        public interface OnItemClickListener {
            void onItemClick(int position);

        }

        public void setmOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener 
 listener) {

            mOnItemClickListener = listener;

        }


        public static class GenreViewHolder extends 
 RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView mTextView;

            public GenreViewHolder(View itemView, final 
 OnItemClickListener listener) {
                super(itemView);
                mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.genreText);


                itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
 {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        if (listener != null) {
                            int position = getAdapterPosition();
                            listener.onItemClick(position);

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public AdapterRecyclerView(ArrayList<DifferentGenres> 
genresItems) {

            mGenreItems = genresItems;
        }


        @NonNull
        @Override
        public GenreViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup 
parent, int viewType) {
            View view = 
LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.genre_item, 
parent, false);
            GenreViewHolder genreViewHolder = new GenreViewHolder(view, 
mOnItemClickListener);

            return genreViewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull GenreViewHolder holder, 
int position) {
            DifferentGenres currentItems = mGenreItems.get(position);
            holder.mTextView.setText(currentItems.getmGenre());


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mGenreItems.size();
        }


        //filter searchview
        public void updateList(ArrayList updated) {

            mGenreItems = new ArrayList<>();
            mGenreItems.addAll(updated);

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        public DifferentGenres getItem(int position){
            return mGenreItems.get(position);
        }


  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The onclicklistener uses data from activity which is not filtered. so position is different in adapter and activity.

You can solve it by passing the object instead of position

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(     DifferentGeners object    );

    }
```